# Filter data based on specific start/end values and calculate time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm having trouble filtering out a specific data set to capture a subset and calculating the duration on that subset.

We have PC's that record when certain tasks turn on; when it was powered on, when the bios loaded, when windows started, when applications started, etc - as well as when those tasks turned off. My goal is focused around when windows turns on and what tasks power on/off until windows is turned off as well as the duration of when windows turned on/off.

Original data set:

```
    PCNum   Code        On/Off      Date        Time
1.  5258    power       on          10/11/2019  10:00:00
2.  5258    bios        on          10/11/2019  10:00:10
3.  5258    windows     on          10/11/2019  10:00:20
4.  5258    steam       on          10/11/2019  10:00:55
5.  5258    origin      on          10/11/2019  10:01:03
6.  5258    origin      off         10/11/2019  10:10:04
7.  5258    steam       off         10/11/2019  10:12:45
8.  5258    windows     off         10/11/2019  10:13:06
9.  5258    bios        off         10/11/2019  10:14:01
10. 5258    power       off         10/11/2019  10:14:22
11. 5258    power       on          10/11/2019  11:34:45
12. 5258    bios        on          10/11/2019  11:34:56
13. 5258    windows     on          10/11/2019  11:35:03
14. 5258    skype       on          10/11/2019  11:35:06
15. 5258    skype       off         10/11/2019  11:56:52
16. 5258    windows     off         10/11/2019  11:57:07
17. 5258    bios        off         10/11/2019  11:57:36
18. 5258    power       off         10/11/2019  11:57:48
```

Using CTE, I've been able to filter my data so it pulls the first iteration on when windows is on and the last iteration of when it turns off, shown here:

```
with minTime_cte (PCNum, Code, Date, Time)
as
    -- find first occurance of on for windows code
    (select PCNum,
            Code,
            Date,
            Time = min(Time)
    from PCData
    where Code = 'windows' and [On/Off] = 'on'
    group by PCNum, Code),

maxTime_cte (PCNum, Code, Date, Time)
as
    -- find last occurrence of off for windows code
    (select PCNum,
            Code,
            Date,
            Time = max(Time)
    from PCData
    where Code = 'windows' and [On/Off] = 'off'
    group by PCNum, Code),

select PCNum,
       Code,
       [On/Off],
       Date,
       Time
from PCData
  join minTime_cte on minTime_cte.Date = Date
    and minTime_cte.PCNum = PCNum
  join maxTime_cte on maxTime_cte.Date = Date
    and maxTime_cte.PCNum = PCNum
where Time >= minTime_cte.Time
    and Time <= maxTime_cte.Time
order by PCNum, Date, Time
```

```
    PCNum   Code        On/Off      Date        Time
1.  5258    windows     on          10/11/2019  10:00:20
2.  5258    steam       on          10/11/2019  10:00:55
3.  5258    origin      on          10/11/2019  10:01:03
4.  5258    origin      off         10/11/2019  10:10:04
5.  5258    steam       off         10/11/2019  10:12:45
6.  5258    windows     off         10/11/2019  10:13:06
7.  5258    bios        off         10/11/2019  10:14:01
8.  5258    power       off         10/11/2019  10:14:22
9.  5258    power       on          10/11/2019  11:34:45
10. 5258    bios        on          10/11/2019  11:34:56
11. 5258    windows     on          10/11/2019  11:35:03
12. 5258    skype       on          10/11/2019  11:35:06
13. 5258    skype       off         10/11/2019  11:56:52
14. 5258    windows     off         10/11/2019  11:57:07
```

Now I need to filter the set down even further to exclude any tasks between the time windows is off and when it's back on again. In this case, it would remove records 7, 8, 9, and 10. I also need to calculate the duration from when windows is on to when it turned off.

Here is what my desired result is:

```
    PCNum   Code        On/Off      Date        Time        DurationOfWindowsSec
1.  5258    windows     on          10/11/2019  10:00:20    0:12:46
2.  5258    steam       on          10/11/2019  10:00:55    0:12:46
3.  5258    origin      on          10/11/2019  10:01:03    0:12:46
4.  5258    origin      off         10/11/2019  10:10:04    0:12:46
5.  5258    steam       off         10/11/2019  10:12:45    0:12:46
6.  5258    windows     off         10/11/2019  10:13:06    0:12:46
7.  5258    windows     on          10/11/2019  11:35:03    0:22:04
8.  5258    skype       on          10/11/2019  11:35:06    0:22:04
9.  5258    skype       off         10/11/2019  11:56:52    0:22:04
10. 5258    windows     off         10/11/2019  11:57:07    0:22:04
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's SQL Server you're using for your data. SSMS is an application that you use to interact with it; it is purely an interface it can't filter your data from your database for you.

Comment: Rather than showing us what your data looks like after you've made changes to it, show us what it looks like before hand; or at least give us the query you already have. It's very difficult for us to tell you how to get from A-C, when you're at B and didn't tell us how you got there.

Comment: Yes, it is SQL Server that houses our databases/tables. I'm writing T-SQL to query my tables and filter the data I'm looking for. It's very possible, I just need help writing it.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that at the end of all records, windows will be off?

Comment: Original dataset added. Yes, it's safe to assume at the end of all records, windows will be off.

Comment: Your existing t-sql would be helpful. Is this as simple as adding: WHERE Code='windows'?

Comment: existing t-sql has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this problem is to figure out what the last `windows` event was, and filter based on that. If the last event was `on`, then we should record it; otherwise we don't. As a bonus, this means that you might not need the previous preprocessing - I haven't tested all of the edge cases, but if your data starts with a `windows` off then you should be good (so you could just union with a dummy row)

Note that I've made some minor changes to the data types for my convenience - I've converted the date and time columns into a single datetime column, and turned the OnOff into a bit column. Looking back, perhaps the second adjustment wasn't necessary. Getting the first adjustment should be easy enough to do; you could do it as part of your pre-processing CTEs.

I've put your data into a temporary table, so it's easier for me to experiment on; you'll likely want to replace every instance of `#test` with the name of your CTE.

SQL Fiddle / data definition:

```
create table #test(
    id int primary key identity,
    PCNum int,
    Code varchar(50),
    OnOff bit,
    dt datetime
)
;

insert into #test(PCNum, Code, OnOff, dt)
values
(5258, 'windows'  , 1,  '10/11/2019 10:00:20'),
(5258, 'steam'    , 1,  '10/11/2019 10:00:55'),
(5258, 'origin'   , 1,  '10/11/2019 10:01:03'),
(5258, 'origin'   , 0,  '10/11/2019 10:10:04'),
(5258, 'steam'    , 0,  '10/11/2019 10:12:45'),
(5258, 'windows'  , 0,  '10/11/2019 10:13:06'),
(5258, 'bios'     , 0,  '10/11/2019 10:14:01'),
(5258, 'power'    , 0,  '10/11/2019 10:14:22'),
(5258, 'power'    , 1,  '10/11/2019 11:34:45'),
(5258, 'bios'     , 1,  '10/11/2019 11:34:56'),
(5258, 'windows'  , 1,  '10/11/2019 11:35:03'),
(5258, 'skype'    , 1,  '10/11/2019 11:35:06'),
(5258, 'skype'    , 0,  '10/11/2019 11:56:52'),
(5258, 'windows'  , 0,  '10/11/2019 11:57:07')
;
```

Actual query:

```
with last_windows(id, dt) as 
(
    select t1.id, max(t2.dt) as dt from #test as t1
    cross join #test as t2
    where datediff(second, t1.dt, t2.dt) <= 0
        and t2.code = 'windows'
    group by t1.id
),
windows_active(id, OnOff) as 
(
select w.id, t.OnOff
from #test as t
    left join last_windows as w on w.dt = t.dt
where t.Code = 'windows'
)
select t.id, t.PCNum, t.Code, t.OnOff, t.dt 
from #test as t
    left join windows_active as wa on wa.id = t.id
where wa.OnOff = 1
    or t.Code = 'windows'
;
```

Explaination: The CTE `last_windows` is responsible for identifying the time of the last `windows` activity for each row (ID). It does this by cross joining the table against itself. The first instance is named `t1`, and the second `t2`. 
`t2` is filtered to only include `windows` rows, and also to only include events at or before `t1`. If we then take the maximum `t2` datetime for each id in `t1`, this represents the time of the last `windows` activity.

Because of the way aggregations work, we can't actually add the OnOff data to `last_windows`. `windows_active` provides a convenience - it joins `#test` to `last_windows`, to effectively add on the OnOff data to `last_windows`. What we are left with is a table that tells us what the last `windows` activity was, for each row in `#test`.

The remainder of the query is trivial - the query joins `windows_active` to `#test` and filters only for when the last `windows` event was 'on'. This also filters out any cases where windows gets turned off, so there's an `or` statement to include all `windows` events.

Note that unfortunately because of the cross join, this query might be slow on large data sets.